# How to port AllJoyn standard to free RTOS ？

Tags: port, rtos, alljoyn

I am using AllJoyn thin client in Marvell platform, but it just a server.  I want to regard it as a client and router.  So the standard AllJoyn can replace it. However the standard just support Linux, Android, iOS, OpenWrt OS; I have no idea how to port it to my own platform Marvell.

- Whether the standard support RTOS?
- If it is true, can anyone give me some advice or data about it.

Comment: Do you mean an RTOS that is free or the specific RTOS called FreeRTOS (one word)?

Comment: You appear to have confused the [*AllJoyn Thin Core Library*](https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/learn/core/thin-core) which has no OS dependencies and no router function with  the *AllJoyn Standard Core Library* which requires OS support but provides router function.  It is nor clear to me what you are asking in that case.

Comment: I mean the RTOS which is free.Marvell support Alljoyn Thin Client,and give its own alljoyn library which contains freetos for user to port it to other OS.

Comment: I is not clear what you mean by "AllJoyn Thin Client" - that is not the name of an AllJoyn product. The capabilities of the AllJoyn Thin ***Core*** Library are clearly described in the documentation, and the *standard core library* clearly has OS dependencies.  All things are perhaps possible; it is a matter of how much work it would require.  For example it would probably be reasonably simple to port the standard core to an RTOS with a POSIX API, but these are not  commonly free AFAIK.

Comment: Marvell company has give solutions for Alljoyn Thin Core Library,and it supports alljoyn on free RTOS.I know the standard core must have OS support,such as Linux,Android,IOS,and OpenWrt etc.I have port the Thin Core Libary to Marvell Alljoyn ,and it runs well.